# How many accounts does a user have?-StackExchange

Tags: stackexchange, user-activity

I am trying to make a **query on stackexchange** that would tell me **for every user**, on which stack community he is present and possibly its reputation on that specific community. It seems there is no indicator in the Sql for this purpose.

Anyone has a solution?
Much appreciated!
Best from Italy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not have a query for every user specifically, by there are a couple existing queries in the [Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) than can be used to count the number of accounts that exist across the network:

- This [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/69700/generate-accountid-comparison) generates a list queries to run. This is building a giant query across all sites in the SE network
- Utilizing the output of the previous point (and skipping the first 4 rows and the last row), we can run the [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/252257)

The results of the second query show the number of accounts that exist on multiple sites.

While it doesn't show the number of accounts for each individual user, it does provide the scope of shared accounts across the network. Querying for each user is probably prohibitively expensive in terms of resources.